# Create and update habtm cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Tables: Sales, Plots(Payment Type) and Recipe.

HABTM: SalePlotRecipe.

```
* EXAMPLE *
SalePlotRecipe (
  id PrimaryKey,
  sale_id ForeignKey,
  plot_id ForeignKey,
  recipe_id ForeignKey
)
```

When creating or updating the sales parcels and revenues should be updated with the data filled in the sale.

A sale may or may not parceled but all sales have a recipe.

The junction of the table I'm doing the right way to join three tables? How to create records for the 3 tables and updates them? What data format? What is the function CakePHP use and how to use? I've tried various forms and to update just duplicating the records

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html here you go

Comment: This is all clearly explained in the docs. What version of CakePHP are you working with. Saving data is significantly different between 2.x and 3.x!

Answer (score 0):

You should use saveAll feature for inserting as well as updating data with sake php.
This will also insert and update data of associated models when you will provide data in particular format.

```
$this->SomeModel->saveAll($data, array(
'fieldList' => array(
    'SomeModel' => array('field_1'),
    'AssociatedModel' => array('field_2', 'field_3')
)
));
```

format for single associated record:

```
Array
(
[Student] => Array
(
    [first_name] => Joe
    [last_name] => Bloggs
)

[Course] => Array
(
    [name] => Cake
)

[CourseMembership] => Array
(
    [days_attended] => 5
    [grade] => A
)

)
```

format for multiple associated records:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [CourseMembership] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [student_id] => 1
        [course_id] => 1
        [days_attended] => 5
        [grade] => A
    )

    [Student] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [first_name] => Joe
        [last_name] => Bloggs
    )

    [Course] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Cake
    )
)
)
```

The update works similar to save if you have primary field in your array then updation else insert. refer this link for further information. You provide structure of other tables then I may help you with the required format http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html